# Prove that limit of $\frac{1^p + 2^p + \ldots + n^p}{n^{p+1}}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{p+1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I stumbled upon an interesting limit of series and I was wondering how could it be solved...

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1^p + 2^p + \ldots + n^p}{n^{p+1}} = \frac{1}{p+1}$$

I tried to divide it into smaller sections ($\frac{1^p}{n^{p+1}}$, $\frac{2^p}{n^{p+1}}$, ..., $\frac{1}{n^p}$), factoring the numerator, but nothing seemed to be the way to go...

I also tried using the squeeze theorem - finding two series with the limit of ${\frac{1}{p+1}}$ but I had no luck with this either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you already familiar with Riemann sums?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio For sure it is...and from not that many days ago. A pity we don't have a user-friendly gizmo to look for past questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Use [Stolz-Ceazaro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) Theorem.

If you are not familiar with Stolz-Cezaro, look at the area under the curve $f(x)=x^p$ from 1 to $n$.

By dividing $[1,n]$ into $n$ intervals of length 1, and using the rectangles with height given by the left end points and right end points to over-under evaluate, you can show that

$$1^p+2^p+...+(n-1)^p \leq \int_{1}^n x^p dx \leq 2^p+3^p+...+n^p$$

This is basically the idea behind the integral test.

Comment: I tried this with the Stolz-Ceazaro theorem and I'm stuck at $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{(n+1)^p}{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}}$. I think I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: @LukášZemina $$(n+1)^{p+1}=n^{p+1}+(p+1)n^p+...$$

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Fischer suggested in the comments, rewrite your quantity as
$$
F_p(n) = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^p+\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^p+\dots+\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)^p}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f\!\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
$$
with $f\colon x\in[0,1]\mapsto x^p$. Then, use the theorem about Riemann sums to relate the limit of $F_p(n)$ to $\int_0^1 f$.

Answer (score 1):

It is the Riemann sum for $I=\int_0^1x^pdx$

Comment: Clement C. already pointed that out.

Comment: Sorry so slow with editing on my smartphone I just hadn't seen

Comment: I find it startlingly odd people is even interested, leave alone able, to enter *and participate* in this site from those unfriendly phones.... "unfriendly" to write, in particular mathematics, with them.

Comment: I usually do math at home behind my desk. Here I am in a boring conference (not math) so I am left with my smartphone. It nevertheless corrects my typos so I don't aprticipate:-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, which uses very few tools from analysis.

Let $P(X)=X^{p+1}-(X-1)^{p+1}$. Expanding with the binomial theorem, you get

$$P(X)=(p+1)X^p +Q(x) \,;\, \deg Q <p$$

Therefore

$$X^p =\frac{1}{p+1} \left(X^{p+1}-(X-1)^{p+1} \right)-\frac{1}{p+1} Q(X)$$

And hence 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^{p}= \frac{1}{p+1} (n^{p+1}-1^{p+1}) -\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p+1} Q(k)$$

To complete the problem, all you have to prove is that if $\deg q <p$ then 
$$\lim_n \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p+1} Q(k)}{n^{p+1}}=0$$

This is easy because it is enough to observe that if $k \leq p-1$ we have

$$0 \leq \frac{1^k+2^k+...+n^k}{n^{p+1}} \leq  \frac{n^k+n^k+...+n^k}{n^{p+1}}=\frac{n^{k+1}}{n^{p+1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

We just need the trivial inequality:
$$ p!\binom{n}{p}\leq n^p \leq p!\binom{n+p}{p}\tag{1} $$
and the identity (it can be proved by induction):
$$ \sum_{k=p}^{N}\binom{k}{p}=\binom{N+1}{p+1},\tag{2} $$
from which:
$$\frac{p!}{n^{p+1}}\binom{n+1}{p+1}\leq \frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p \leq \frac{p!}{n^{p+1}}\binom{n+p+1}{p+1}. \tag{3}$$
Now the claim follows from squeezing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Faulhaber's Formula which states:
$$
\sum^n_{k=1}{k^p}=\frac{1}{p+1}\sum^p_{j=0}{(-1)^j{p+1 \choose j}B_j\ n^{p+1-j}}
$$
Where $B_j$ is the $j$th Bernoulli number. Dividing through by $n^{p+1}$, you get that asymptotically the only term that matters is when $j=0$ where the value is $1$ otherwise the sum converges to $0$. Overall the sum is therefore:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1^p + 2^p + \ldots + n^p}{n^{p+1}} = \frac{1}{p+1}
$$

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula