# Evaluate the limit $ \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{1^a+2^a\cdots+n^a}{n^{a+1}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The exact question is-
Find the real value(s) of $a (a \ne -1)$ for which the limit $$ \lim_{ n \to \infty} \frac{ 1^a+2^a\cdots+n^a}{(n+1)^{a-1}[ (na+1)+(na+2) \cdots+(na+n)]} = \frac{1}{60}$$

I simplified it a bit to get that limit. However,  I got the answer from Wolfram Alpha $\frac{1}{a+1}$ without a solution and an assumption that $|a|<1$ however the answer that I got on further solving (and given) is $a=7$ and $a=-\frac{17}{2}$

How is it solved?

Comment: This page could also be helpful: [Limit of the sequence $\frac{1^k+2^k+...+n^k}{n^{k+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936924/limit-of-the-sequence-frac1k2k-nknk1). Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150391/evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac-sum-k-1n-kmnm1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478344/what-is-the-result-of-lim-n-to-infty-frac-sumn-i-1-iknk1 for example.

Comment: I think Stolz Cezaro theorem could help

Comment: Yes, thanks for mentioning that. I didn't see that simple Riemann sun albeit it was right there in front of me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression is equal to

$$\frac{1}{n}\left(  \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^a +\cdots + \left(\frac{n}{n}\right)^a \right).$$

This is a Riemann sum, so your limit is the integral of an easy function.

Comment: Thanks. How could I miss that! Damn!

Answer (score 1):

Beside the Riemann sum, consider that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^a=H_n^{(-a)}$$ which is a generalized harmonic number.

Using asymptotics
$$H_n^{(-a)}=n^a \left(\frac{n}{a+1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{12
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)+\zeta (-a)$$ making for the question in title
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^a }{n^{a+1}}\sim \frac 1{a+1}+\frac a {2n}$$ So, the limit and also how it is approached.

For the question in text,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (na+i)=\frac{1}{2} \left((2 a+1) n^2+n\right)$$ and the same approach would lead to
$$\sim \frac {n^a} {(n+1)^a} \frac{2(n+1)}{(1+a)(1+2a)n}\to \frac 2{(1+a)(1+2a) }$$

Comment: I guess, that's not in highschool syllabus

Answer (score 1):

Useful link related to the first equation;

[Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^m}{n^{m+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150391/evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac-sum-k-1n-kmnm1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Limit of the sequence $\frac{1^k+2^k+...+n^k}{n^{k+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936924/limit-of-the-sequence-frac1k2k-nknk1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[$\lim_{{n}\to {\infty}}\frac{1^p+2^p+\cdots+n^p}{n^{p+1}}=?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108798/lim-n-to-infty-frac1p2p-cdotsnpnp1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Showing that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1^k+2^k+...+n^k}{n^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{k+1}$ using integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693769/showing-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1k2k-nknk1-frac1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Prove that limit of $\frac{1^p + 2^p + \ldots + n^p}{n^{p+1}}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{p+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1136629/prove-that-limit-of-frac1p-2p-ldots-npnp1-is-equal-to-fra?noredirect=1&lq=1)

$$1^a+2^a+...+n^a\sim\frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1}$$ so we could write this limit :

$$ \lim_{ n \to \infty} \frac{ 1^a+2^a\cdots+n^a}{(n+1)^{a-1}[ (na+1)+(na+2) \cdots+(na+n)]} =\lim_{ n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1}}{{(n+1)^{a-1}[ n^2a+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}]}} = \lim_{ n \to \infty}\frac{2n^{a+1}}{{(a+1)n(n)^{a-1}n[2a+1]}} = \frac{2}{(a+1)(2a+1)}=\frac{1}{60}$$

So $(a+1)(2a+1)=120$ and $a=7,\frac{-17}{2}$

Comment: How do you know/prove that first fact which you used?

Comment: I add some resources. You could use similar question in the right of your browser too find other similar questions. Please don't forget to mark correct solution question as "tik" to be in access other people. Thanks.